# How to use media query and selectors at the same time using scss?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

So I am creating a web app that supports dark mode.

If the device prefers dark mode by default, it will use the dark mode by the media query `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)`.

But I also want to have a feature that users can manually switch to dark mode by adding an attribute to the body: `data-theme="dark"`.

So I tried this:

```css
// ...

.ChatScreen {
    background-color: #eee;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark), body[data-theme="dark"] {
    .ChatScreen {
        background-color: #000;
    }
}
```

It gives me this error while compiling:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/scss/app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/scss/app.scss)
SassError: Invalid CSS after "...me: dark), body": expected "{", was '[data-theme="dark"]'
        on line 107 of src/scss/screens/_chat.scss
        from line 6 of /Users/****/src/scss/app.scss
>> @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark), body[data-theme="dark"] {

   -------------------------------------^
```

How can I achieve this without duplicate these codes?

Comment: why not make 2 separate declarations. Even if it will look like a duplicate. Sometimes it's the best way to go. `body[data-theme="dark"] { ... } ` and `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { ... } `

Comment: @MihaiT If that's the only solution, I think using mixins is the best way to go as *apincik* mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    &[data-theme="dark"] {
   .ChatScreen {
        background-color: #000;
    }
   }
  }
}
```

You can look at sass mixins and define your dark styling and then include that rule wherever you need.

**Edit**

```
@mixin dark-theme {
  .ChatScreen {
        background-color: #000;
    }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    @include dark-theme;
}

body {
    &[data-theme="dark"] {
        @include dark-theme;
   }
}
```

Comment: But this code only works while the user's browser matches the query. I want it to be either match the query or inside the `body` which has `data-theme="dark"` attribute.

Comment: It works, but will the names clash if I include multiple scss files which have the mixins with the same name? Or should I name them differently? Kinda new to scss.